# Pandas: control new column names when merging two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two Pandas dataframes together and control the names of the new column values.

I originally created the dataframes from CSV files. The original CSV files looked like this:

```
   # presents.csv
   org,name,items,spend...
   12A,Clerkenwell,151,435,...
   12B,Liverpool Street,37,212,...
   ...
   # trees.csv
   org,name,items,spend...
   12A,Clerkenwell,0,0,...
   12B,Liverpool Street,2,92,...
   ...
```

Now I have two data frames:

```
df_presents = pd.read_csv(StringIO(presents_txt))
df_trees = pd.read_csv(StringIO(trees_txt))
```

I want to merge them together to get a final data frame, joining on the `org` and `name` values, and then prefixing all other columns with an appropriate prefix.

```
org,name,presents_items,presents_spend,trees_items,trees_spend...
12A,Clerkenwell,151,435,0,0,...
12B,Liverpool Street,37,212,2,92,...
```

I've been reading the documentation on [merging and joining](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). This seems to merge correctly and result in the right number of columns:

```
ad = pd.DataFrame.merge(df_presents, df_trees,
                        on=['practice', 'name'],
                        how='outer')
```

But then doing `print list(aggregate_data.columns.values)` shows me the following columns:

```
[org', u'name', u'spend_x', u'spend_y', u'items_x', u'items_y'...]
```

How can I rename `spend_x` to be `presents_spend`, etc?

Comment: You could use the `suffixes` option to have them named `spend_presents`, etc. Will that work? Otherwise, use the `rename` function.

Comment: @itzy yes, thank you! please submit as an answer and i will accept!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `suffixes` option in the merge function does this. The [defaults](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) are `suffixes=('_x', '_y')`.

In general, renaming columns can be done with the [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method.

Answer (score 9):

You can rename all the columns of *ad* by setting its *columns* as follows.

```
ad.columns = ['org', 'name', 'presents_spend', 'trees_spend']
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is adding suffix to the columns of your dataframe before merging:

```
ad.columns = 'ad_' + ad.columns.values
```