# rename column names while merging dataframs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am 5 files in this format. All files have Sentences and Date columns.

[image]

I am merging all files by reading them in dataframes. This is my code.

```
def blend_all(all_files):
    li = []
    for file in all_files:
        name = pd.read_csv(file)
        li.append(name)
    df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Date', how='outer'), li).fillna('Void')
    return df_merged
```

This is the result of above code. As you can see, the column names are random and repeating. I want each column different for example Sentences_1, Sentences_2 ... I also want Date to be the first column.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: You can use `.suffix(<string>)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338374/pandas-control-new-column-names-when-merging-two-dataframes

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html you can change suffixes of your columns, please check suffixes parameter. To make Date first you can just make ```df=df[['Date', all_other_columns]]```

Comment: for order: `col = df.pop("Date");df = df.insert(0, col.name, col)`

Comment: `df.columns = [f"{c}_{idx}" if c.startswith(('Sentences')) else c for (idx,c) in enumerate(df.columns)]`

Comment: @Manakin Your solution is giving this error. `Grouper for 'Date' not 1-dimensional`
and output of fist line is df with 10 column of Sentence, Date and same content in all columns.

Comment: df.set_index=df[''Date']

Comment: @AMi that would set it as index but won't bring in start